# Error with cmake while downloading open cv

Tags: opencv, cmake

I'm trying to get opencv working on my mac. I'm trying to follow this tutorial: http://tilomitra.com/opencv-on-mac-osx/. The only problem is after I download cmake and run the command cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" .. I get an error message in my terminal saying CMake Error: The source directory "/Users/dannyhalawi/Desktop/opencv2.framework" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.

Which is true, it does not contain CMakesList.txt. However, I'm not sure how to get it in there?

Any advice?

Comment: You must be inside the directory containing the extracted OpenCV files. Then run: `mkdir build` and `cd build`. Then you can run `cmake` command.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have run the previous two lines to create and change to the `build` folder:

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
```

The `..` at the end of the `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..` command means that CMake will look in the parent folder for `CMakeLists.txt`. So here are the steps you should take:

1. Extract the source files to a new folder. In your case `/Users/dannyhalawi/Desktop/opencv2.framework`.
2. Change to that folder.
3. Run the commands from your tutorial.

If you need some help understanding how CMake works at a higher level, I posted a codecast about [starting a C++ project with CMake](http://v1ntage.io/2017/07/15/episode-002-an-opinionated-start-to-a-cpp-project/) that might be of use to you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I went ahead and created a new folder on my desktop and placed the opencv2.framework in there. Then in that folder I created a new directory called build. Then I did cd build to go inside that directory and then ran cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" .. but still I'm getting the same error CMake Error: The source directory "/Users/dannyhalawi/Desktop/project" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't able to load the page your tutorial refers to at http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide to download the OpenCV tarball. However I was able to go to the official [OpenCV releases](http://opencv.org/releases.html) page, download the latest source release and I verified that there is a CMakeLists.txt file there. Can you do a file search and see if CMakeLists.txt is somewhere in the extracted directory tree?